# has_many and sum named_scope

Tags: activerecord, group-by, sum, join, named-scope

I have this situation:

```
Stories has many Tasks
Tasks have an integer called hours_left
```

I need a **named scope to find Stories which all its tasks has more than 0 hours left**.

Based on [this post](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=28709). I wrote this:

```
class Story
  has_many :tasks
  named_scope :uncompleted, { 
    :joins=>["INNER JOIN tasks ON tasks.story_id = stories.id"],
    :group=> 'stories.id',
    :select=>'stories.*, SUM(tasks.hours_left) AS sum_amount',
    :having=>"sum_amount > 0"
  }
end
```

But `Story.uncompleted` returns an empty array.

Can you help me?

Comment: I also noticed that if I remove the :having=>"sum_amount > 0" condition I get all the stories: Those with 0 hours left has the attribute hours_left set to "0" but the rest (those I want) have hours_left set to nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. That code actually works, the problem is that it returns nil as result of the sum if any of the tasks has hours_left = nil.  I validated presence of hours_left and that's all.