# Rails 3 - How to use filter results of sum operation?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a Rails 3 app, and I need to return back a list of players where the sum of points_received per player, is greater than a specified amount.

I have tried this:

```
Answer.sum(:points_received, :group => 'player_id').having("points_received > 5")
```

but of course this gives me an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `having' for #

Answer model is defined as:

```
 create_table "answers", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "player_id"
    t.integer  "round_id"
    t.string   "response"
    t.integer  "points_received"
  end
```

So I understand that sum is returning back an ordered hash of player_id, sum(points_received), but I only want to see the results where the sum(points_received) is greater than a specified value.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you believe it, just after I posted this, I then had a thought on swapping some syntax around and got the result.  This is what I ended up doing:

```
Answer.group(:player_id).having("sum(points_received) > 5").sum(:points_received)
```

this returned me back the hash of player_ids and sum(points_received) for only the ones where the sum is greater than 5.

Thanks for reading anyway.  Maybe this will help someone one day!

Comment: you can't accept your own answer for 2 days...  or otherwise I would.

Comment: any idea how to do it in rails 2.5?

Comment: never mind.. i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491229/has-many-and-sum-named-scope